# EntityFramework Sorting a subset

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a list of messages. In each message, there are a list of response types. I need to pull the query in such a way that the messages are ordered by ID and the response types are also ordered by ID. They are NOT ordered by ID in the database.

```
messageResponse.Messages = (from m in db.Messages.Include("ResponseType")
    .SomeMagicSubSortThing("ResponseType.ID")
    select m).OrderBy(m1 => m1.ID).ToList<Message>();
```

This should result in:

```
Message   ID    Col1    Col2
-- ResponseType  ID    Col1    Col2
```

...like so:

```
1     MessageA    MessageB
--  1   ResponseTypeC    ResponseTypeD
--  2   ResponseTypeQ    ResponseTypeR
--  3   ResponseTypeX    ResponseTypeZ
--  4   ResponseTypeL    ResponseTypeM

2     MessageE    MessageF
--  1   ResponseTypeG    ResponseTypeH
--  2   ResponseTypeI    ResponseTypeJ
--  3   ResponseTypeB    ResponseTypeS
--  4   ResponseTypeL    ResponseTypeC
```

Right now, I can get the messages in order, but the response types are in whatever order the database has them. How can I sub-sort the response types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is ThenBy():

```
messageResponse.Messages = (from m in db.Messages.Include("ResponseType")
.SomeMagicSubSortThing("ResponseType.ID")
select m).OrderBy(m1 => m1.ID).ThenBy(n=>n.ResponseType.ID).ToList<Message>()
```

**UPDATE**

In your entity can you simply define a calculated property like:

```
class Message {
   public ICollection<Response> Responses {get; set;}
   public ICollection<Response> SoretedResponses {
       get { return this.Responses.OrderBy(n=>n.Response); }
   }
}
```

Or am I still missing the issue?

Comment: The ResponseType here is an entity collection (not a standard LINQ subset) because I'm using Entity Framework. I don't have direct Linq access (that I know of) to the properties within the ResponseType object. I SINCERELY wish this was straight-up LINQ, but it's not.

Comment: Updated it with another possible option

Comment: The second approach is one that we tried to implement. Due to OTHER problems with the code (not the implementation you suggested) we couldn't use it. But had we built things properly to begin with, the second solution would be a great approach.

Answer (score 0):

EF doesn't do this nicely, but you do have two options:

---

1) Use a `Select` clause in your Linq to Entities query:

```
var messages = db.Messages
  .OrderBy( o => o.ID )
  .Select( o => new
    {
      Message = o,
      ResponseTypes = o.ResponseTypes.OrderBy( x => x.ID ),
    }
  )
  .ToList()
;
```

This is the only way to get EF to sort child properties on the database server.

Your output `List` will have elements of the anonymous type in the `Select`

---

2) Use Linq to Objects on the output `List<Message>` to sort the collections of `ResponseType`:

```
List<Message> messages = db.Messages
  .Include( o => o.ResponseTypes )
  .OrderBy( o => o.ID )
  .ToList()
;

foreach( var message in messages )
{
  message.ResponseTypes = message.ResponseTypes.OrderBy( x => x.ID ).ToList();
}
```

This gets all the records from the database and then sorts them in memory.

The output list will have elements of type `Message` with the navigation property populated.